# is DjangoRestFrameWork really needed for a website

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, web, django-rest-framework

Is it worth it to use DRF+Ajax+bootstrap to build a website where no app is needed, or is it better to stick to the normal django template language without even Ajax? I want to avoid using angular since I don't want things to get complicated.

I want to create a website where a user or an admin logs in and accesses a different set of views and performs different actions.
Sorry for my primitive question, I'm a newbie in web development and Django.

Comment: Why do you think you need Django REST Framework to begin with?

Comment: it's just for learning purpose since i might use it in my personal app soon

Answer (score 2):

Django REST Framework is only necessary if you're building a RESTful API; An HTTP service that reads and writes data, usually as JSON payloads.

Services are typically created to allow external clients such as mobile apps, single page applications (React, Angular, etc.) or 3rd parties to gain access to your data.

It is not necessary to create a service if you just want a traditional "form-based" web application. What you're describing in your question is totally possible with the standard Django implementation. User logins, user access levels, database access via the ORM and templating are all built in. All without any need for a REST service.

You can always add Django REST Framework later when you know you'll need RESTful services since DRF uses the same models that the normal views do, it just wraps them in serializers.

Comment: In case the website will be extended later to a mobile version and I decide to use DRF, do you know if there is somewhere an example or tutorial about creating a user session with ajax?

Comment: This isn't a forum, if you have another question, start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you're suggesting easily without any special additions or changes to Django. Just because a certain way of development is popular does not mean it works in every situation.